# how can we define closed set or open set for a set of matrices?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we consider  the set of all matrices in $M_{2}$(R) such that neither eigenvalue is real .Is the set open or closed?

Comment: Consider the function that maps a matrix to the discriminant of its characteristic polynomial. Is this a continuous map? What about the preimage of $(-\infty,0)$?

Comment: To answer the question of your title: You can topologize $M_n(\mathbb R)$ by the inner product $\langle A,B \rangle := \operatorname{TR}(A^tB)$.

Comment: Equivalently, we can identify $M_n(\Bbb R)$ with $\Bbb R^{n^2}$ just by listing out the elements in some order, and then using an appropriate topology on $\Bbb R^{n^2}$.

Comment: the preimage of of (−∞,0) will be the whole set. But I cannot understand if I don't know which are the open sets of the given set then how I can conclude about the continuity of the map. And how it is related  to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** The eigenvalues of a matrix $A \in M_2(\Bbb R)$ are the roots of the polynomial
$$\det (\lambda I_2 - A) = \lambda^2 - (\operatorname{tr} A) \lambda + \det A,$$ and these roots will be nonreal iff the discriminant $$\Delta(A) := (\operatorname{tr} A)^2 - 4 \det A$$ of $A$ is negative.

Comment: Please explain the next steps to proceed.

Comment: @jaggu You're considering the set of $A$ satisfying $\Delta\left(A\right)<0$. Can you see why such a set would contain a neighbourhood of each element?

Comment: @J.G. No, I can't. Please help.

Comment: @J.G. No, I can't. Please help.What is the neighbourhood of each element of the set?

Comment: @jaggu Let $S$ denote the desired set of $\Delta<0$ matrices. Andre's comment noted an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$, which we can use to define a distance metric. Let $B\left(A,\,r\right)$ denote the radius-$r$ open ball in $S$ of centre $A$. Since $\Delta$ is continuous in all entries of $A$, for sufficiently small $r>0$ we have $B\left(A,\,r\right)\subseteq S$.

Comment: @J.G.I could not understand this statement "Since Δ is continuous in all entries of A". Please help.